# Persistent Object Reference Not Set Error With [No relevant source lines]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been happily developing an MVC/Sitecore App and all was fine.

However all of a sudden I got an error telling me that I had a `Object reference not set to the instance of an Object` going on.  The error page pointed to a line that had nothing other that a closing brace.

I tried removing the lines of code in the view that could be causing the error but the error remained on the same closing brace.

So I commented out the whole block including the closing brace. Now I am getting the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\1a47b3ff\21a05ef3\App_Web_kieomnc4.1.cs    Line: 0
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   ASP._Page_Views_MyCompany_Common_AddressEdit_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\1a47b3ff\21a05ef3\App_Web_pjrqnchq.1.cs:0
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +124
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +109
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +379    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +108
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +879

I have stopped the WWW service completely, closed Visual Studio, deleted all the temp files from the Temporary ASP.NET folder, restarted the service, reloaded Visual Studio but still the error remains.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this, I deleted the website in IIS then recreated it and the error disappeared. Same files in the same location, just IIS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS
2. Stopped the IIS server
3. Delete the folders under the following directory:
   ***c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root***
4. Start the IIS server back up.
5. Try loading your page again.

Comment: If you read the question fully you will see I tried this but it didn't work.